# Find the secure name (sn.exe) container name for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, sn

I have a software that must be signed by a pfx certificate during the build. The machine on which I build the solution is a fresh new machine and we are trying to not perform any configuration by hand but only via scripts during the build process.

When I launch the build I get this error from `msbuild`

> [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3214,5):
>
> Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: Key.pfx. The key
>   file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the
>   certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong
>   Name CSP with the following key container name:
>   VS_KEY_07C5CCD85188D111

Usually I solve this by executing in the Developer Console of Visual Studio on the build machine:

`sn -i VS_KEY_07C5CCD85188D111 path\to\Key.pfx`

But, as told before, I would like that the build automatically retrieves the container name and imports the certificate as a step prior to the `msbuild` command. The problem I have is that I don't know how to retrieve the container name Visual Studio wants to use, because it changes depending on the machine I run the build on.

Do you know how Visual Studio computes that container name? Or how to retrieve it in anyway?

Comment: You already have at least one rather fool-proof way of finding it that is automatable: perform a build that's intended to fail and grep the output. (Of course this is a clumsy and sub-optimal solution, but it *can* be automated. Just thought I'd point that out.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, currently it is my only idea to solve the problem but I don't like it so much. I wondered if exists a better and "standard" way to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SnInstallPfx.exe](https://github.com/honzajscz/SnInstallPfx). It will determine the container name and import the pfx. It's not standard but uses the standard methods to determine the container name

For more information, see the following [blog article](https://dhvik.blogspot.com/2020/01/building-strong-named-assemblies-in.html).